# UWP and prism MEF

Tags: prism, mef, uwp

Does someone have been dealing with development in Universal Windows Platform stuff and dependency injections through Prism Mef? Because by now I use WPF and this Prism and Prism Mef and now I need to develop for UWP and I can't find anything about Prism Mef re-usability into UWP.

Answer (score 5):

MEF and Windows Runtime (Windows 8/8.1) have never played well together. We've created a POC back in the days and found it a real burden to make it work. I'm not sure if much is changed since the release of Windows 10 UWP and if things play well together now, but it's certainly possible to [use MEF together with UWP](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7d275f3-e52a-44f6-8939-2f0f90d67e68/uwp-net-native-mef-help-needed-possibly-with-runtime-directives-defaultrdxml?forum=wpdevelop).

Prism does currently **not** support MEF for UWP. Feel free to log an issue on [Prism's GitHub](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues) to request support and the team will look into the feasability. If you would implement it yourself, don't hesitate to send a pull request :).

Comment: Do you know what it is that causes the problem? I'm imagining something about reflection.

Comment: It's been a few years, but reflection might be one of the main reasons indeed. Plus the need to add the assemblies as references (which removes the flexibility of MEF).